# Reproducir cancion tras otra con MciSendString, "problema" con "wait"

Tags: c++, winapi

Buen dia, quiero que mi codigo pueda reproducir una cancion tras otra, logre hacerlo con "wait", pero el problema es que no quiero que se "congele" el programa mientras corre el mp3, si no que este disponible para las otras funciones como "pause" o "stop"

Me he tratado de informar y tal parece que el comando "status" me podria servir, pero no entiendo como usarlo para lo que necesito.

Asi que agradeceria su ayuda, Gracias.

Aqui esta el codigo en el "case IDC_Play1:"

```
if ((SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_CHECK1, BM_GETSTATE, NULL, NULL)) == BST_CHECKED) {//codigo para reproducir solo una cancion(no hay problema aqui)}

else {
    int cuenta = SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST1, LB_GETCOUNT, NULL, NULL);
    int indice = 0;
    while (indice != cuenta) {
        char auxi[10] = "";
        UINT index = SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST1, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
        SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST1, LB_GETTEXT, index, (LPARAM)auxi);
        if (strcmp(auxi, "") == 0) {
            MessageBox(NULL, "No se selecciono cancion", "ERROR", MB_ICONERROR);
        }
        else {
            char Cnum[10];
            aux = inicio;
            aux = aux->sig;
            do {
                _itoa_s(aux->folio, Cnum, 10);
                if (strcmp(auxi, Cnum) == 0) {
                    strcpy_s(szFileName, aux->mptres);
                    bmp1 = (HBITMAP)SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_Imagen1, STM_GETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0);
                    bmp2 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, aux->imagen, IMAGE_BITMAP, 140, 120, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
                    SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_Imagen1, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)bmp2);
                }
                else {
                    aux = aux->sig;
                }
            } while (strcmp(auxi, Cnum) == -1 || strcmp(auxi, Cnum) == 1);

            ShowWindow(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_Play1), SW_HIDE);
            ShowWindow(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_Pause1), SW_SHOW);

            char comillas[MAX_PATH] = "\"";
            char comillas2[MAX_PATH] = "\"";
            strcat_s(comillas, szFileName);
            strcat_s(comillas, comillas2);
            char musica[MAX_PATH] = "open ";
            strcat_s(musica, comillas);
            strcat_s(musica, " type mpegvideo");
            mciSendString(musica, NULL, 0, 0);
            char musica1[MAX_PATH] = "play ";
            char esperar[MAX_PATH] = " wait";
            strcat_s(musica1, comillas);
            strcat_s(musica1, esperar);

            mciSendString(musica1, NULL, 0, 0);
            char parar[MAX_PATH] = "stop ";
            strcat_s(parar, comillas);
            mciSendString(parar, NULL, 0, 0);
            char cerrar[MAX_PATH] = "close ";
            strcat_s(cerrar, comillas);
            mciSendString(cerrar, NULL, 0, 0);

            index++;
            SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST1, LB_SETCURSEL, index, NULL);
            SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST2, LB_SETCURSEL, index, NULL);
            SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST3, LB_SETCURSEL, index, NULL);
            SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST4, LB_SETCURSEL, index, NULL);
            SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST5, LB_SETCURSEL, index, NULL);

            indice = index;
        } //else
    } //while
}//else
```

Por ultimo, una duda sobre stackoverflow, como inserto correctamente un bloque de codigo?

Comment: Puedes usar el boton `{ }` en el editor de texto (5° de izquierda a derecha) o poner 4 espacios a cada linea de codigo o encerrar algo dentro del caracter `  asi quedaria: `c = 1`

Answer (score 1):

> el problema es que no quiero que se "congele" el programa mientras corre el mp3

Lo que describes es el comportamiento habitual de las rutinas sincronas, no realiza ninguna rutina nueva (como pausar o parar) hasta finalizar la rutina en curso (reproducir). Así pues la pregunta es si `mciSendString` es una rutina síncrona.

#### Problema

Me ha costado mucho encontrar información al respecto, en la documentación oficial de Microsoft no indica si la función es síncrona o asíncrona pero en [este hilo de MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/1a34960d-e503-42f3-9b55-58122826f446/synchronous-or-asynchronous) apunta a [esta documentación](http://mireality.co.uk/writing/technology/os2-multimedia-chapter/media-control-interface/) que indica lo siguiente (la traducción y el resaltado son míos):

> Los comandos REXX incluyen `mciRxSendString`, `mciRxGetErrorString`, y `mciRxGetDeviceID` que proporcionan acceso a las API **`mciSendString`**, `mciGetErrorString`, y `mciGetDeviceID` respectivamente. Estos comandos REXX se enlazan con llamadas a `mciRxInit` y `mciRxExit`. Las llamadas a estos comandos deben contener la palabra clave `wait` o no usar nada. Esto es porque cuando se usa la palabra clave `notify`, se envía una notificación a un proceso de ventana. Cuando PMREXX tiene un procedimento de ventana, REXX no lo tiene. **Al no especificar ni `wait` ni `notify`, se realiza una llamada asíncrona sin notificación de finalización**.

Por lo tanto, cuando usas `wait` la llamada es síncrona, y es por eso que se queda congelado.

#### Sugerencia

Para poder enviar comandos de `pause` y `stop` mediante `mciSendString`, deberías *transformar* la llamada `mciSendString(musica1, NULL, 0, 0);` en asíncrona. Para ello puedes usar la librería [`<thread>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) de C++11:

```
// Funcion que invoca mciSendString con play y wait sobre el
// archivo indicado.
void play_wait(const char *file) {
    char musica1[MAX_PATH] = "play ";
    char esperar[MAX_PATH] = " wait";
    strcat_s(musica1, file);
    strcat_s(musica1, esperar);
    mciSendString(musica1, NULL, 0, 0);
}
```

En primer lugar creamos la función que hace la llamada, esta función la podemos llamar asíncronamente de la siguiente manera:

```
char comillas[MAX_PATH] = "\"";
char comillas2[MAX_PATH] = "\"";
strcat_s(comillas, szFileName);
strcat_s(comillas, comillas2);
char musica[MAX_PATH] = "open ";
strcat_s(musica, comillas);
strcat_s(musica, " type mpegvideo");
mciSendString(musica, NULL, 0, 0);

std::thread asincrono(play_wait, comillas);
asincrono.detach();
```

La función [`thread::detach`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) hará que la función `play_wait` se ejecute asíncronamente en otro hilo *desenganchando* el objeto `asíncrono` del contexto actual, así que no deberás preocuparte por el mismo. Cuando la llamada encerrada dentro de `play_wait` finalice, el hilo finalizará también. Mientras esté el hilo en ejecución el archivo se reproducirá y *supongo* que el dispositivo podrá seguir recibiendo comandos asíncronamente.

#### Advertencia

No he usado nunca `mciSendString` ni he podido probar el cósigo, podría no funcionar. Hazme saber si encuentras otros problemas relacionados.